# how can I fix this sp in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to write a store procedure in phpmyadmin but I get this error, also I did it in navicat but I get the same error, can someone help me to fix it?, help really appreciated thanks

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' IN comienzo int, IN termino int ) BEGIN SELECT usuario.nombre, LEF' at line 2**

this is my store procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE store(
  IN actualUser varchar(20)
)

SET @comienzo2 = comienzo;
SET @termino2 = termino;
SET @actualUser2 = actualUser;

BEGIN
SELECT
usuario.nombre,
LEFT(titulo, 20) as titulo,
LEFT(mensaje, 20) as mensaje,
correo.fecha,
correo.id_correo,
correo_has_usuario.correo_id_correo,
correo_has_usuario.destinatario_id_usuario,
correo_has_usuario.eliminado,
correo_has_usuario.leido
FROM
correo_has_usuario 
Inner Join correo ON correo_has_usuario.correo_id_correo = 
correo.id_correo
Inner Join usuario ON usuario.id_usuario = 
correo.usuario_id_usuario
WHERE
correo_has_usuario.destinatario_id_usuario = actualUser AND
correo_has_usuario.eliminado =  0 ORDER BY correo.fecha DESC
LIMIT comienzo,termino;
END$$
```

Hello thanks again for answer I get this error message #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @termino2 = termino; SET @actualUser2 = actualUser; BEGIN PREPARE stmt ' at line 8

Comment: You haven't used `DELIMITER` to change the delimiter to `$$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed the data length off of the VARCHAR on line 2

`IN actualUser varchar(20)` for example

Your limit statement is also incorrect and will throw out an error. Limits must be numeric or a local variable when used in a stored procedure. See

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

> Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using
>   integer-valued routine parameters or local variables as of MySQL
>   5.5.6.

To do this you'd have to set up your arguments as variables like

```
SET @comienzo2 = comienzo;
SET @termino2 = termino;
SET @actualUser2 = actualUser;
```

Then rather than simply run your select statement you must prepare it then execute it.

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT ... LIMIT ?, ?';
EXECUTE stmt USING @comienzo2, @termino2;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This will also be the case for your where statement.

Example:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE store(
  IN actualUser varchar(20),
  IN comienzo int,
  IN termino int
)

SET @comienzo2 := comienzo;
SET @termino2 := termino;
SET @actualUser2 := actualUser;

BEGIN
PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT
    usuario.nombre,
    LEFT(titulo, 20) as titulo,
    LEFT(mensaje, 20) as mensaje,
    correo.fecha,
    correo.id_correo,
    correo_has_usuario.correo_id_correo,
    correo_has_usuario.destinatario_id_usuario,
    correo_has_usuario.eliminado,
    correo_has_usuario.leido
    FROM
    correo_has_usuario 
    Inner Join correo ON correo_has_usuario.correo_id_correo = 
    correo.id_correo
    Inner Join usuario ON usuario.id_usuario = 
    correo.usuario_id_usuario
    WHERE
    correo_has_usuario.destinatario_id_usuario = ? AND
    correo_has_usuario.eliminado =  0 ORDER BY correo.fecha DESC
    LIMIT ?,?;'
EXECUTE stmt USING @actualUser2, @comienzo2, @termino2;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
$$
```

Comment: so how can I define a limit in the store procedure? I dont understand If I need to pass a limit can you explain a little bit more? thanks for answering

Comment: I update my answer with mi question, I still I dont get it to work in navicat or phpmyadmin, also I edit the tags I am using php and pdo

Comment: Sorry if my answer was misleading. I've updated it with a syntax error free example but I've not tested it because I don't have the database structure.

Comment: I update my question with a new error thanks againg for answer

Comment: can I send you the script sql?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4646/discussion-between-ben-swinburne-and-georgebecj)